# How to add values in even position of lists in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add values in even position of lists like these:

```
|     ID       
|-------------------------------------------------------------
|  2002070     [4.5, 4.2, 3.7, 4.8, 4.4, 4.4, 4.3, 4.3, 4.8, ...
|-------------------------------------------------------------
|  2002740     [4.8, 4.8, 4.9, 4.9, 5.1, 5.1, 5.4, 5.4, 5.1]
|-------------------------------------------------------------
|  2003010     [4.9,     4.7,     5.5]
                      ^         ^
                   add new    add new
```

I used the code:

```
Values = [4.5, 4.2, 3.7, 4.8, 4.4, 4.4, 4.3, 4.3, 4.8 ,4.8, 4.8, 4.9, 4.9, 5.1, 5.1, 5.4, 5.4,4.9, 4.7, 5.5]
ID = [2002070, 2002070,2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2003010,2003010,2003010]
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID, 'Values': Values})
lists = df.groupby('ID').Values.apply(list)
for i in range(len(lists)):
    for j in range(0, len(lists[i]), 2):
        j.append(3)
```

So at the end I should find a longer list for each ID.
I am not able to cycle on different ID and then to add a value between the previous and the next one. I tried with append but I found some errors.
Could you help me to fix this?

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-53d234399cc4> in <module>()
      4 lists = df.groupby('ID').Values.apply(list)
      5 for i in range(len(lists)):
----> 6     for j in range(0, len(lists[i]), 1):
      7         j.append(3)
      8 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    765         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    766         try:
--> 767             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    768 
    769             if not is_scalar(result):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   3116         try:
   3117             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 3118                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   3119         except KeyError as e1:
   3120             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: What do you want to add?

Comment: by even position you mean the index in the list ?

Comment: if you have list then use `insert(position, value)`

Comment: if you get error then show it in question. We can't run your code and can't read in your mind to see error. And even better create minimal working code with example data directly in code so we could run it, see problem and test ideas.

Comment: I want add the mean between the previuos and the next value in the list, for each ID @Chris

Comment: I would add a number between the previuos and the next value, so for each even position I would add a number but I don't want to replace that are just there. @PieroCosta

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it is more clear @furas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting iterables into each cell in a pandas DataFrame is an anti-pattern; most pandas methods are expecting a scalar value. So my advice is to skip creating lists if possible.

According to your comments you want to do a similar operation to up-sampling (but with an RangeIndex instead of DatetimeIndex). Here's a solution with pandas.

```
Values = [4.5, 4.2, 3.7, 4.8, 4.4, 4.4, 4.3, 4.3, 4.8 ,4.8, 4.8, 4.9, 4.9, 5.1, 5.1, 5.4, 5.4,4.9, 4.7, 5.5]
ID = [2002070, 2002070,2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002070, 2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2002740,2003010,2003010,2003010]
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID, 'Values': Values})
# lists = df.groupby('ID').Values.apply(list)

# get the rolling averages and concatenate to df
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df.groupby('ID')['Values'].rolling(2).mean()
            .dropna().reset_index('ID'),
        df
    ]
).sort_index()#.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output

```
         ID  Values
0   2002070    4.50
1   2002070    4.35
1   2002070    4.20
2   2002070    3.70
2   2002070    3.95
3   2002070    4.80
3   2002070    4.25
4   2002070    4.40
4   2002070    4.60
5   2002070    4.40
5   2002070    4.40
6   2002070    4.30
6   2002070    4.35
7   2002070    4.30
7   2002070    4.30
8   2002070    4.80
8   2002070    4.55
9   2002740    4.80
10  2002740    4.80
10  2002740    4.80
11  2002740    4.90
11  2002740    4.85
12  2002740    4.90
12  2002740    4.90
13  2002740    5.00
13  2002740    5.10
14  2002740    5.10
14  2002740    5.10
15  2002740    5.25
15  2002740    5.40
16  2002740    5.40
16  2002740    5.40
17  2003010    4.90
18  2003010    4.80
18  2003010    4.70
19  2003010    5.10
19  2003010    5.50
```

Left the index so you could validate that it is the correct result. But it would be best to reset it to a `DefaultRangeIndex`.

Comment: Thank you @RichieV, this is what I am looking for!!